# Mongoose and typescript error while doing transaction and rollback on user while creating seller

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose-schema

[image: postman data for request][image: here is tge error]I'm working on a mern project but while I want to create two types of user such as seller and user at a time I'm getting some unusual error like seller validation failed: budget: Path 'budget is required' can't solve this problem since last 3 days . I struggling a lot with this problem.

Here is my user service and controller :

```
import ApiError from '../../../errors/apiError'
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { ISeller } from '../seller/seller.interface'
import { IUser} from './user.interface'
import { User } from './user.model'
import { Seller } from '../seller/seller.models';
import status from 'http-status'


const createSeller = async (user: IUser, seller: ISeller): Promise<IUser | null> => {
  console.log(seller,user,  'line number 11')
  user.role = 'seller';

  let newUserAllData = null;
  const session = await mongoose.startSession();

  try {
    session.startTransaction();


    const newSeller = await Seller.create(seller, { session });

    if (!newSeller.length) {
      throw new ApiError(status.BAD_REQUEST, 'Failed to createSeller');
    }

    user.seller = newSeller[0]._id;
    console.log(user.seller, 'user.seller')

    const newUser = await User.create(user, { session });

    if (!newUser.length) {
      throw new ApiError(status.BAD_REQUEST, 'Failed to create User');
    }

    newUserAllData = newUser[0];
    console.log(newUserAllData)

    await session.commitTransaction();
    await session.endSession();

  } catch (error) {
    await session.abortTransaction();
    await session.endSession();
    console.log(error, 'serice error from catch and throw')
    throw error;
  }
console.log(newUserAllData, 'service line 47')
  if (newUserAllData) {
    newUserAllData = await User.findOne({ id: newUserAllData._id }).populate({
      path: 'seller', 
    })
  }
 console.log('new user all data from user service',newUserAllData)
  return newUserAllData;
}
```

and here is the controller:

```
import { Request, RequestHandler, Response } from 'express';
import { UserService } from './user.services';
import status from 'http-status';
import sendResponse from '../../../shared/sendResponse';
import catchAsync from '../../../shared/catchAsync';
import { IUser } from './user.interface';



const createSeller:RequestHandler = catchAsync(async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const {seller,  ...data } = req.body;
    const result = await UserService.createSeller(seller, data);
    console.log(result, 'here is the logger information about result')
    sendResponse<IUser>(res, {
        statusCode:status.OK ,
        success: true,
        message: "Successfully user has been created",
        data: result,
    });
    console.log(data, 'line number 20 controller')
})
```

here is interface and model:

```
import { Model, Types } from 'mongoose';
import { ISeller } from '../seller/seller.interface';
import { IBuyer } from '../buyer/buyer.interface';

export type IUser = {
    password: string, 
    role: "seller" | "buyer", 
    seller?: Types.ObjectId | ISeller,
    buyer?: Types.ObjectId | IBuyer,
}

export type IUserFilters = {
    searchTerm? : string;
}

export type UserModel = Model<IUser, object>


import {  Schema, model } from 'mongoose'
import { IUser, UserModel } from './user.interface'


export const userSchema = new Schema<IUser>({
    password: {
        type: String, 
        required: true, 
    }, 
   
    role: {
        type: String, 
        enum: ["seller", 'buyer'],
        required: true,
    },
    seller: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'Seller', 
    }, 
    buyer: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'Buyer',
    }
})

export const User = model<IUser, UserModel >("User", userSchema);

and this is seller model

import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose'
import { ISeller, SellerModel } from './seller.interface'

const sellerSchema = new Schema<ISeller>(
  {
    name: {
        firstName: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        lastName: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
      },
    address: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    phoneNumber: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    budget: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    income: {
      type: Number,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  },
)

export const Seller = model<ISeller, SellerModel>('Seller', sellerSchema)
```

Comment: The Seller schema marks "budget" as a required field.  Does the "seller" passed in req.body contain such a field?

Comment: Yes, Im passing it properly

Comment: What does the console.log with "line number 11" output?

Comment: line number returns these:
{ password: 'abrakadabra' } {
  name: { firstName: 'Mr. Babull', lastName: 'Bro' },
  phoneNumber: '01711111111',
  address: 'Chattogram',
  budget: 0,
  income: 0
}